# Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated on Robot Framework

Tags: firefox, robotframework, autotest, geckodriver, selenium2library

I have a form with five fields and I am trying to input text into the last field.

An example of my script is:

[input]     [id=combo-1234-textfield]       [text]
I already got the ID but when it tries to input text on the ID found, it says the Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated. But I can input text manually like normal. Due to the readonly=false.

I have checked that the ID's are correct.

Does anybody know what the issue is here?

Note; I am using FireFox as the browser.

Comment: Have you tried placing a sleep just before the test? this is great for debugging IMO. Then if it works, you know that you need to wait for the elements to be available, and use an appropriate wait.

Comment: Have you tried first clicking on the element and then input or send keys?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use keywords like

1.Wait Until Element Contains
2.Wait Until Element Does Not Contain
3.Wait Until Element Is Not Visible
4.Wait Until Element Is Visible
5.Wait Until Page Contains
6.Wait Until Page Contains Element,etc

These keywords and its details are available in the below link
http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html